# PhpStorm configuration of PHPstan for Symfony with Docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, phpstorm, phpstan

I am trying to make PHPstan work for a dockerized Symfony project using [this template](https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker). The project use PHP 8.1.16. Works fine.

Now I want to push it a little bit to fully use the PHP CLI installed in my docker container instead of the local one.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.brocksi.net/blog/configure-phpstan-phpstorm-use-php-docker-container/) to make PhpStorm use the PHP CLI installed in my docker container. Then configured PHPstan and PHP CS Fixer to use this CLI.

Everything is detected fine but PHPstan can't make use of the path provided for `container_xml_path` in `phpstan.neon`.

Here is my `phpstan.neon`:

```yaml
includes:
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/extension.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/rules.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-symfony/extension.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-symfony/rules.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/extension.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/rules.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-strict-rules/rules.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules/rules.neon

parameters:
    symfony:
        container_xml_path: var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml
        console_application_loader: bin/console
        consoleApplicationLoader: tests/console-application.php
    level: 9
    paths:
        - src
        - tests
```

And this is the error I get when PHPstan automatically run :

[image: PhpStorm error regarding PHPstan]

The file path is okay, but the file only exist in the container, my local `var` dir is empty.

Is that the problem or am I missing the point? And how can I link it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
What was missing is the "Connect to existing container ('docker-compose exec') ." step described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-phpstan.html#prerequisites)
I wasn't able to see it because i choose "Docker" over "Docker compose" in the dialog box [step 5 of this tutorial](https://www.brocksi.net/blog/configure-phpstan-phpstorm-use-php-docker-container/).

Also, if someone struggle with a similar problem, make sure you use correct docker version (`docker-compose` or the latest `docker compose`).

To use the new `docker compose`, check the box  "Use Compose V2 (beta)" under Settings Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker > Tools.